# Get same effect as ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject without taking up more height

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have to add `location` from this stylesheet:

```
const mapStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    height: 400,
    width: 400,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  location: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    width: 400,
    alignItems: 'center',
  }
})
```

to my autocomplete (`<Location />`) so that on Android the autocomplete list will overflow the other components.

E.G.:

```
    <Container style={mapStyles.location}>
    <Location />
    </Container>
```

However it seems to push the elements below the `<Location />` down to about the device screen height below it (so there is a full blank screen under the `<Location />` and then the other components appear. How do I get the same effect as `...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject` withought moving components below it further down the screen?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject` will be replaced with this properties ([source](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/98fc4373fc0143abadda01013749074706d03c55/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js#L29-L35)):

```
const absoluteFillObject = {
  position: 'absolute',
  left: 0,
  right: 0,
  top: 0,
  bottom: 0,
};
```

It works for your `<Location />` component (it needs to be absolute to "overflow" the other elements), but not for your container.
Makes your container full height with `flex: 1`, the other element in your container and it should work.

```
const mapStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    width: 400,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  location: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    width: 400,
    alignItems: 'center',
  }
})
```